Fundamental group of a hatching
Let $X = (\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathcal{T}$ be the usual subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in $X$. Let's call this space a hatching, because it resembles the drawing technique of hatching.
What is the fundamental group of $\mathcal{T}$?
I have little experience on determining fundamental groups, so I have problems reasoning about them here. I'm imagining a very complicated group because there are just so many holes the loop can circle around in various ways.

I do not think you can identify it with any group you are familiar with. For instance, it is locally free but not free. Why do you need it?

I doubt there is any simple description.  If you consider a sequence of squares with rational endpoints that converge to the origin, you can see that $X$ contains a Hawaiian earring as a retract, so its fundamental group contains the fundamental group of the Hawaiian earring which is rather complicated.

Well, this space has some relevance to my research, and I thought it would be good to see how the fundamental groups are determined with this "simple" example. But perhaps the answer is that in general fundamental groups are tricky, and most of the time there is no clean answer, even if the space can be simply described? I do have a more modest goal too: to show that this space is not simply connected.

If you just want to show that the space is not simply connected, this is much easier: Find a simple "square" loop $L$ in $X$ and show that it is nontrivial in a suitable subset of $R^2$ which contains $X$.

Given that a retract of a simply connected space is simply connected, the non-simply connectedness would be shown if some square were a retract of the space. For the retraction I could intersect a ray with the square, where the ray origin is some point with irrational coordinates inside the square.

@kaba $\pi_1$ does not really do well with "limit behavior:" the shrinking wedge of circles of Eric's comment superficially resembles a wedge sum of countably many copies of $S^1$, whose fundamental group is easy to compute, but the "shrinking" part introduces pathologies: a loop can now wrap around infinitely many of the circles and you get something much less well-behaved. Your space $X$ is essentially all limit behavior: it's dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so is its complement, so you get this same pathology around every point.

@kaba For a non-simply connected retract, see Eric's comment. You might want to also check out this and this for some insight onto how one might attempt to get a handle on such computations.

@EricWofsey Just out of curiosity, is there an easy to way to see why the Hawaiian earring is a retract of this space? I start thinking of specific ways to do it, but perhaps there is some general tool?

@BenSteffan I see. Incidentally, this kind of limit behavior is essential for me. I'm using such spaces as counterexamples (in dimension theory). I now understand that I probably cannot describe their fundamental groups or homotopy groups. But what I probably can do is determine their n-connectedness.
